# How can I pass value in the stripe checkout.form?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am using the stripe checkout.js, it's working good, but I want to pass the users fields in the billing name, billing city, billing postal code and billing country if the user has login. How can I do that?

```
<form action="" method="POST">  
{% csrf_token %}                                            
<script
 src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
 data-key="{{ data_key }}"
 data-amount="{{ stripe_total }}"    
 data-name="Store"
 data-description="{{ description }}"
 data-image="{% static 'img/pic.png' %}"
 data-email = "{{ user.email }}"
 data-locale="auto"
 data-currency="cad"
 data-shipping-address="false"
 data-billing-address="true"                                
 data-allow-remember-me="false"                               
 data-label="Pay with card"
>
</script> 

</form>
```

Is there any way to pass it in the stripe checkout.js or I will create my custom form.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no way to pre-fill a billing address in checkout. The only thing you could prefill is the user email. 
Most probably the think you could do is to create your custom form or considering using Stripe Element which is more customizable [0]
[0] https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but in a different way

```
stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardElement, {
 billing_details: {
 name: 'Jenny Rosen',
},
}).then(function(result) {
 // Handle result.error or result.paymentMethod
});
```

You can visit here https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference.

Tha another way is you can pass data as in your question through ajax call then on views, use the stripe payment method from this link https://stripe.com/docs/development#python, it will help you out in this.